# 'dig' between docker containers returns internal IP instead of external IP

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dnsdist, powerdns-recursor

First, sorry for the lenghty post, but I don't know how to boil it down to less than this. I have already cut a lot of unnecessary configuration stuff to end up with the basic info needed.

I am setting up a dns recursor pair, ns1 and ns2, each on a separate server.
Each server contains the powerdns-pair of dnsdist frontent and recursor backend, running in separate containers, one for each, managed by docker-compose, based on tcely/dnsdist from Docker Hub.

```
ns1: 192.168.0.1
ns2: 192.168.0.2
```

My objective is to have dnsdist able to query both recursors, in it's loadbalancing function, so i have a dnsdist.conf that, cut down to the essentials look like this:

```
newServer{address='192.168.0.1:5300', order=1}
newServer{address='192.168.0.2:5300', order=2}
setServerPolicy(firstAvailable)
setLocal('0.0.0.0')
```

Largely the same for both servers but with the order reversed, so primary recursor should be the "local" one.

I won't confuse things with the recursor.conf, suffice to say that it allow-from 0.0.0.0/0, so the recursor does not block anyone from querying it at this point.

Finally we get to the point:

When I start the pod, dnsdist comes up with the following log errors:

```
...
Marking downstream 192.168.0.1:5300 as 'down'
Marking downstream 192.168.0.2:5300 as 'up'
...
```

When I try to find out why it thinks the local recursor is down, by entering into the dnsdist container and run "dig" from there, i get this:

```
/ # dig @192.168.0.2 -p 5300 a.root-servers.net. +short
198.41.0.4
/ # dig @192.168.0.1 -p 5300 a.root-servers.net. +short
;; reply from unexpected source: 172.20.0.1#5300, expected 192.168.0.1#5300
```

So - it seems when i query the other container's external IP, it replies with the internal IP.  If I could query the other containers internal ip, i..e in this case 172.20.0.1, I would do so, but that IP is local to the container and changes every time it is restarted.

So, the question is, how do I get around this?  Is there a way in Docker to hardcode the internal IP addresses used, or to get the container/dnsdist to ignore the fact that it get a reply from another IP address than expected?

EDIT - for clarification:  Docker automatically assigns network names, so for example, i can 'ping recursor' and it will resolve to the resolver-containers private IP address.  I just can't use this for anything because dnsdist.conf only accepts IP addresses, and as I started out explaining, the IP addresses are set randomly by docker when the container starts.

Comment: Does your DNS server have two network interfaces?

Comment: They're virtual machines so in theory they could have multiple interfaces each, but the idea is to just have one per server, to limit the administrative overhead.

Comment: Seems like you have network configuration issue. That is why I've asked you about number of interfaces.

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood your question. The servers only have one nic at this time, the standard ensxxx type. In addition it has docker0, some virtXXXX and some BR-XXXX interfaces, but I suppose they were created by docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (or at least one) solution is to create a local network for the pod (container pair):

```
version: '3'

services:
    dnsdist:
      image: 'tcely/dnsdist'
      container_name: powerdns-dnsdist
      restart: 'unless-stopped'
      tty: true
      stdin_open: true
      command: ["--disable-syslog", "--uid", "dnsdist", "--gid", "dnsdist", "--verbose"]
      volumes:
        - /data/docker/volumes/dnsdist-recursor/dnsdist:/etc/dnsdist
      expose:
        - '53'
        - '53/udp'
      ports:
        - '53:53'
        - '53:53/udp'
      networks:
          dnsnet:
              ipv4_address: 172.28.1.10
    recursor:
      image: 'tcely/powerdns-recursor'
      container_name: powerdns-recursor
      restart: 'unless-stopped'
      command: ["--disable-syslog=yes", "--log-timestamp=no", "--local-address=0.0.0.0", "--setuid=pdns-recursor", "--setgid=pdns-recursor"]
      volumes:
        - /data/docker/volumes/dnsdist-recursor/pdns-recursor:/etc/pdns-recursor
      ports:
        - '5300:53'
        - '5300:53/udp'
      networks:
          dnsnet:
              ipv4_address: 172.28.1.11

networks:
    dnsnet:
      ipam:
        driver: default
        config:
          - subnet: '172.28.1.0/24'
```

Now you can setup dnsdist.conf as follows

```
newServer{address='172.28.1.11:53', order=1}
newServer{address='192.168.0.2:5300', order=2}
setServerPolicy(firstAvailable)
setLocal('0.0.0.0')
```

restart

repeat and rinse.